# Resources for Mishna Berura Yomi

Tags: torah-study, mishnah-berurah

I would like to join the daily study of Mishna Berura. I would love to jump right in and join them wherever they are at, rather than start from the first page on my own. I think the set schedule will help me. I am having a tough time finding the daily schedule and daily shiurim to listen to.

1. Would someone be able to help me find a schedule that details the requirements for each day?
2. Would someone be able to help me find shiurim that are reliably posted each day?

Bonus question: it is an amud or a full daf?

Comment: https://www.dirshu.co.za/  Dirshu is currently on their second cycle, and are in middle of Hilchos Sulkah. It's one Amud a day

Comment: @user what do you mean based on Dirshu? It's based on Mishna Berura. Dirshu has a schedule of 1 amud a day and it takes about 8 years to finish. They have daily shiurim. It's 5 days a week and Friday and shabbos is for chazzarah

Comment: @user sorry, he's a better link https://www.dafhalacha.com/

Comment: There's a few Mishnah Berurah yomis. Which are you interested in? Dirshu?

Comment: Interested in joining a set calendar. If there are multiple options I guess I'll need ti pick one.